# How to set chart area line in step

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have this chart (build with Reporting Services) and it works.

In this chart, I have used the chart area, so now if the data for one or more color, change, I see the line, then I want to see a scale.

This is my chart:

[image]

Then I want to see my chart similar this:

[image]